# how to get info on failed authentication to domain - security audit?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, authentication, audit

Setup:
1 Windows Server 2012 box as Domain Controller, named DC1.
2 Windows Server 2012 R2 boxes, S1 and S2, on the same network, same config, joined to the domain.

Issue:
At random times, S1, S2 or both will not allow me to RDP on the boxes with a domain user, with the message "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed". RDP with a Local admin works. This is usually solved with a restart of S2.

Question:
How do I check the logs on DC1, to see these failed authentication events ? Do I have to enable some kind of security audits and download some applications/SDK with extra management tools ?

Comment: Somehow S1 and S2 are dropping off the domain, which is bad. I would look at DNS settings and the DNS server(s) and also make sure basic connectivity between S1 & S2 and the DC(s) is solid. A one-stop test is to ping the FQDN for the windows domain (e.g., yourdomain.local) from S1 or S2. Make the sure IP that it pings is the IP of one of your DCs and that it pings successfully.

Comment: Just woke up another server, S3, didn't use it in about 3 weeks, and I get the same error. Logged in on S3 as the local admin and checked for all these resources - they are all online: test.local, dc1.test.local, s1.test.local.

Comment: What DNS server are these servers using? Presumably only the DNS server that hosts your AD DNS zone?

Comment: DC1 is configured as the only DNS server.

Comment: Reviewing system log on member servers is a better approach. When member server loses its domain membership, it's normally a permanent thing until you eliminate the root cause, so your statement "resolve with a restart" is kind of interesting. And why would rebooting S2 resolve issues on S1 (if I read your post correctly)? Check if time is sync'ed among servers; check if there is any resource exhaustion so that essential service(s) are not working (netlogon, rpc, etc.)